# React native keyboard auto closing /component reloading when setting state

Tags: react-native

I have  a form for logging in users.

The email and password states are in the `App` component and are passed down to the `Login` component, which are passed down to a , like so:

`<TextInput value={text} onChangeText={(e)=> setText(e)}/>`

I've looked at some solutions like storing the text inside a new state and then setting it when the input is not active, but this still has many bugs because I have multiple inputs.
Any how I can prevent the keyboard from hiding? And even putting autoFocus is bugged.

Answer (score 0):

You could use context to share this state instead of passing it down as a prop as it will trigger some unwanted renders, I did a small example based on the explanation you gave about your project.

https://codesandbox.io/s/contextformexample-vrzvy?file=/src/App.js

In the example you are not passing the states as props, preventing the render that force the keyboard to hide, besides that you still have access to the values if you want, using the hook "useContext" from the component LoginScreen for example.

I'll share the code bellow in case the link above does not works.

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, FlatList, TextInput } from "react-native";

const LoginContext = React.createContext({
  email: "",
  password: ""
});
const LoginProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <LoginContext.Provider value={{ email, setEmail, password, setPassword }}>
      {children}
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
};

const LoginForm = () => {
  const loginContext = useContext(LoginContext);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        value={loginContext.email}
        onChangeText={loginContext.setEmail}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        value={loginContext.password}
        onChangeText={loginContext.setPassword}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const LoginScreen = () => {
  return <LoginForm />;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <LoginProvider>
      <LoginScreen />
    </LoginProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Just a reminder: I've put all the components and providers in the same file in this example to keep it simple but mind that you should probably organize it in separated file to keep your project clean.

Success on your project!